# MySQL - Too many nested sub-expressions in a full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mysql-8.0

I have a full-text search query with many sub-expressions like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM search_table s
WHERE MATCH (s.search) AGAINST ('+(failure* protection*) +(math* police*) +(insect* hall*) +(library* variety*) +(world* reality* disk*) +(area* debt*) +(disaster* judgment*) +(ability* user*) +(studio* session* examination*) +(contribution* son*) +(menu* employment*) +(wedding* problem*) +(midnight* pizza*) +(cigarette* bird*) +(drama* policy* politics*) +(comparison* difficulty* clothes*) +(knowledge* currency* apple*) +(historian* lady* activity*) +(inflation* opinion* chocolate*) +(measurement* gene*) +(recommendation* solution*) +(engineering* comparison*) +(history* t-promotion*) +(setting* hair*) +(software* investment*) +(conversation* success*) +(user* college*) +(profession* difference*) +(fact* worker*) +(ambition* solution*) +(a-tradition* chocolate*) +(assignment* loss* government* goal*) +(sympathy* selection*) +(river* quantity*) +(reaction* world* charity*) +(president* office* touch-affair*) +(administration* classroom* argument*) +(ear* oven*) +(performance* assumption*) +(instance* finding*) +(resource* science*) +(situation* wood* tooth*) +(consequence* operation* independence*) +(wealth* grandmother*) +(manager* loss*) +(revolution* currency* application*) +(classroom* leader*) +(student* salad* criticism*) +(ladder* perception*) +(energy* courage*) +(preference* possibility*) +(painting* interaction*) +(son* election*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I got this error is response:

> Too many nested sub-expressions in a full-text search

Seems self explanatory enough but a google search for "**Too many nested sub-expressions in a full-text search**" returns almost nothing.

- <strike>How many sub-expressions am I allowed?</strike>
- What is the limit based on?
- Is there a configuration setting for this?

**UPDATE:**

Through trial and error I've determined that I am allowed up to 32 sub-expressions. Not sure if this is some arbitrary number or based on resources or a setting.

Comment: I have not heard of such a limit, much less a setting.  You might do what I recommend for `OR` -- convert it into the `UNION` of several `SELECTs`.

Comment: @RickJames - I don't really see how it's realistic to convert the same BOOLEAN logic into an `OR` condition or `UNION`. There are 127 nested groups - each with at least 2 words.  That's a *minimum* of 1.7014118e+38 queries - therefore Impossible.

Comment: Does the query work well enough without any parens?  Without any plusses?  Without either?

Comment: Idk much about the syntax for Full Text search but is each sub-expression being `OR`ed or `AND`ed with each other sub-expression here? If the former, then to Rick's point, you can choose to divide up the query into however many `UNION`s you want - 127 if you want one `UNION` per sub-expression or more manageable would be to split the query into 5 or 10 `UNION`s total which will probably minimize the number of sub-expressions below the limit you're hitting.

Comment: @RickJames - no it would be a completely different query without those.

Comment: @J.D. - Read my comment above, it would be this many queries: 170141180000000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, so your comment makes no sense to me. If each sub-expression is being `OR`ed, then your math is incorrect and / or you have a misunderstanding of how `OR`s and `UNION`s work. If you want to answer my question of "*is each sub-expression being `OR`ed or `AND`ed with each other sub-expression here?*" then I may be able to better explain how to rewrite your code.

Comment: @J.D. - I'm asking about the limitations mentioned in the error and what they are based on. What makes you think I want to rewrite this code? Regarding your question, it would be better if you posted it *as a question* but I'll try to explain: `+(failure* protection*) +(math* police*)` means `(failure* OR protection*) AND (math* OR police*)`.  That yields 2^2 possible matches. Every sub-expression increments the exponent.  With 127 sub-expressions you are looking at a minimum of 2^127. Some of those sub-expressions actually have multiple OR conditions so the number is even higher.

Comment: @J.D. - This may help you understand the syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: "*I'm asking about the limitations mentioned in the error and what they are based on. What makes you think I want to rewrite this code?*" - Your only option may be that you have to re-write the code **because** of the limitations. In any case, thanks for explaining the syntax. If I can think of a relational equivalent query that simplifies the predicate, I'll let you know. You could probably write 127 subqueries to apply the combined `AND` predicates without having to write out every possible combination, but even that is *bleh* IMO. Maybe just a few (4?) smart subqueries could do the trick.

Comment: @J.D. - I appreciate your effort and interest but you should know I have plenty of options for how this gets dealt with within the application itself.  My purpose here is simply to gain a better understanding into what on earth the DBMS is blathering about since I failed to find anything documented anywhere about this limitation.